# Powershell - Removing Special characters from Files within Subfolders

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a solution to remove these special characters "#" "&" "%" from a large amount of files. The files are currently in a folder named **"Banyan Foundation, Inc - Copy"** within an external hard drive named **"My Book (E:)".**
There are 38,282 files and 8,454 folders in the above folder.

I am trying to move them from the external hard drive into a new storage platform on Onedrive. However, some files will not copy over due to the special character's that some of the file names have.

I am very new to Powershell, I used it for a few months back in college but have not touched it since. I have been searching for hours for a solution but I am having issue's with setting the location (It is on an external hard drive) and choosing the location of the exact file I want to clean up.

Thank you!

Comment: How do you want to handle collisions? If you have two files `test#1.txt` and `test&1.txt` for example?

Comment: Great question! I do not think that will be a problem but if it does occur what is the easiest method to fix it? These files are not searched or opened regularly by any means. They are mostly for records.

Comment: *but I am having issue's with setting the location* - what issues?

Comment: I don't know how to word it correctly lol I have never used to set location function.

Comment: "I have been searching for hours for a solution" - what were you searching for? Set-Location is nothing to do with anything, you need `Rename-Item`   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094615/renaming-files-with-powershell ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211748/how-can-i-rename-files-in-powershell ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32687155/powershell-rename-file-name-and-keep-extension ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37197515/how-to-split-string-and-rename-files-in-powershell ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522601/rename-files-in-powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- $Pattern is a regular expression matching any of `#` or 
  `&` or `%`
- this script doesn't take care of possible duplicate names.

---

```
$Pattern = '#|&|%'
$Start = "E:\" 
$Folder = "Banyan Foundation, Inc - Copy"
GCI -path $Start -Directory -recurse $Folder |ForEach {
  GCI -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -File | Where Name -match $Pattern|
    Rename-Item -NewName {"$($_.FullName)" -replace $Pattern,''} -whatif
}
```

If the output looks OK remove the `-whatif` in the last line